# Mac OS X - what is the relationship between daemon and jvm

Tags: macos, jvm, daemon

From what I can understand, on Mac OS X, daemon is something running in the background (same as Windows Service). Can I make the connection between daemon by saying that a dameon written in Java is considered to be a JVM? I read some where people mentioned about daemon thread and jvm thread, how are they related?

Comment: A JVM, or Java Virtual Machine, is the runtime that handles the execution of your java program. Therefore your program cannot be a JVM by being a daemon, unless you write a JVM in Java, which would be fairly unusual.

Comment: @Charlie Martin:  Daemon and JVM are readily available on Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvm. It would be nice to know if @tom has read those.  I would be nice of they could ask more **specific** questions including actual quotes from the articles that showed the source of any confusion or difficulty.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: It's not quicker to answer when you're unclear on what the asker knows, doesn't know, has read and hasn't read.  One can, of course, guess or assume and write an answer that's useless.  That doesn't seem quicker.

Comment: @SLott Well, somehow I usefully answered the guy's question first time out, got him to ask a second question, and solved his underlying problem, while giving him useful background and  an oppotunity to use `man`.  Which of us was more productive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  A JVM -- Java Virtual Machine -- is the executable that runs your java program.  A *daemon* is any program that runs without being attached to a particular terminal, like, oh, launchd.

So consider running a java program from the command line: the jar file is myapp.jar and you type

```
 $ java -jar myapp.jar
```

That starts an executable program  at the path `/usr/bin/java`, which is just a regular program.  It just happens to be one that includes the interpreter for java instructions, the "java *virtual machine*".  It runs and simulates that special abstract java machine, and runs until all the normal threads of the java program terminate.  It then returns a return code and ends.  Since that java process was launched by the shell, it's a *child program* of the shell, and the shell gets back a notice that it completed.

Now, it's possible to write a program, for example in C, that creates a process that isn't owned by a shell; its parent becomes the process with process ID 1, which is called *init(1)* on most UNIX systems, or *launchd* on Mac OS/X.  A process that is owned by PID 1 runs until it's either stopped by a shutdown command, or it terminates itself (or crashes.)

Those processes are called *daemons* after the more-than-human spirits in Greek mythology.  They're called that because (a) it's a cute name; (b) they have "supernatural powers" compared to a regular user program; and (c) old time hackers like cute names.

Comment: Thanks charlie! I have a Java program that I want to run it in the background (like Windows Service) and automatically starts when the system starts, is it doable on Mac OS X? 

Daemon is basically a program that starts automatically and runs in the background. Does that mean that my java program is essentially a daemon?

Comment: You bet, Tom.  Read `man 1 launchd` and `man 1 launchctl` -- you basically can ask launchd to take the program and run it for you as a daemon.  Another approach is to run from the command line and "disown" it: `$ java -jar myapp.jar & disown`.

Comment: The OS/X launchd approach, by the way, is a fair bit easier than the old-fashoned way, requiring a fairly arcane config file in `/etc/inittab`.